# How to debug gRPC server crashing without any error?

Tags: c++, grpc

I've copy pasted gRPC server from [gRPC helloworld example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_server.cc).

It starts listening for RPC in specified port, but when I call the RPC with a copy pasted client, it crashes with "Aborted (core dumped)" and in client side I get error message "Endpoint read failed".

I tried debugging this by including some output statements in RPC function implementation, but the execution never reaches the point.

There are no other error messages, is there some flag to make the failure more verbose for debugging?

Comment: Instead of using log messages use a _real debugger_.

Answer (score 2):

Besides `GRPC_VERBOSITY` as mentioned above, you should also set `GRPC_TRACE` to something like `http,secure_endpoint` and use a debug build. For a complete list of options: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md

Comment: I've been to that page and it's nice that it shows what the env variables are, but it doesn't say how to set them.  I'm on windows, and setting environment variables in cmd.exe with set or setx has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC the build succeeds, so I don't think this question needs the #bazel tag.

Looks like you can set the `GRPC_VERBOSITY` environment variable to values "DEBUG", "INFO", or "ERROR"(https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/fead0879460da1a7990d43472f770bb4fe8145f6/src/core/lib/support/log.cc#L68) in order to control logging.